# Backbone проблема при обновлении страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvc, backbone.js, underscore.js

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста. После успешной регистрации загружает допустим next view в которую рендериться еще 2 view

```
success: function(success) {
          this.NextView = new NextView();
          $('.wrapper').html(this.NextView.el);
        },
```

Когда уже пользователь зарегистрировался и находится на next view по нажатию обновить(f5) меня перебрасывает снова на регистрацию. Как сделать, чтобы это не происходило. Может что в роутере прописать надо?/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно, в роутере должна быть прописана та страница с nextView. И вообще, после регистрации, у вас должен быть переход на нужный route, а не запуск другой view. Роутер сам должен будет его запустить.